# Got a "There's already a question exactly like that" error trying to "Save" from an edit

Tags: bug, edits

I was editing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967389) (already closed as a dup, which is fine). The edits were just to fix up the formatting because it looked awful.

When I went to save the edits, I got the bouncing red box error about the question title being essentially the same as that of another question. That was perfectly fair, but I didn't touch the title; it was already allowed (apparently) when the OP posted it in the first place.

I re-worded the title with specific content from the question to get around the bouncing red box (which is hard to fool). However I still think it's a little weird that the error would apply to an *edit* on a question that's already in the system. Maybe I don't fully understand the philosophy behind the bouncing red box; perhaps it was intended to get me to do something like what I actually did with the title.

Comment: Meh, just vote to delete. That question doesn't increase the chances that someone find the canonical question.

Comment: @Braiam agreed; the question involved doesn't have much value. That's not really important to my question, as I presume that the bouncing red box error about the title might have occurred had I been editing the best question ever asked.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the rules used to be different. When they changed, nobody went back and changed the titles.

You can find more of these through [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45773/find-identical-titles-no-closed-questions). (It was running before, but SEDE might be down right now. I'll see about adding more stats to this when it's up.)

Comment: I really don't understand this answer. What rules used to be different? How would old rules affect a question just asked today?

Comment: @Pointy I din't realize it was just asked today. I wonder if they cheated the system... They might have JS disabled.

Comment: Oo that's a good point.